# multiple if else conditions in pandas dataframe and derive multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, dataframe

I have a dataframe like below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
raw_data = {'student':['A','B','C','D','E'],
        'score': [100, 96, 80, 105,156], 
    'height': [7, 4,9,5,3],
    'trigger1' : [84,95,15,78,16],
    'trigger2' : [99,110,30,93,31],
    'trigger3' : [114,125,45,108,46]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['student','score', 'height','trigger1','trigger2','trigger3'])

print(df2)
```

I need to derive Flag column based on multiple conditions.

i need to compare score and height columns with trigger 1 -3 columns.

Flag Column:

1. if Score greater than equal trigger 1 and height less than 8 then Red --
2. if Score greater than equal trigger 2 and height less than 8 then Yellow --
3. if Score greater than equal trigger 3 and height less than 8 then Orange --
4. if height greater than 8 then leave it as blank

How to write if else conditions in pandas dataframe and derive columns?

Expected Output

```
  student  score  height  trigger1  trigger2  trigger3    Flag
0       A    100       7        84        99       114  Yellow
1       B     96       4        95       110       125     Red
2       C     80       9        15        30        45     NaN
3       D    105       5        78        93       108  Yellow
4       E    156       3        16        31        46  Orange
```

For other column Text1 in my original question I have tried this one but the integer columns not converting the string when concatenation using astype(str) any other approach?

```
def text_df(df):

    if (df['trigger1'] <= df['score'] < df['trigger2']) and (df['height'] < 8):
        return df['student'] + " score " + df['score'].astype(str) + " greater than " + df['trigger1'].astype(str) + " and less than height 5"
    elif (df['trigger2'] <= df['score'] < df['trigger3']) and (df['height'] < 8):
        return df['student'] + " score " + df['score'].astype(str) + " greater than " + df['trigger2'].astype(str) + " and less than height 5"
    elif (df['trigger3'] <= df['score']) and (df['height'] < 8):
        return df['student'] + " score " + df['score'].astype(str) + " greater than " + df['trigger3'].astype(str) + " and less than height 5"
    elif (df['height'] > 8):
        return np.nan
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You need chained comparison using upper and lower bound

```
def flag_df(df):
    
    if (df['trigger1'] <= df['score'] < df['trigger2']) and (df['height'] < 8):
        return 'Red'
    elif (df['trigger2'] <= df['score'] < df['trigger3']) and (df['height'] < 8):
        return 'Yellow'
    elif (df['trigger3'] <= df['score']) and (df['height'] < 8):
        return 'Orange'
    elif (df['height'] > 8):
        return np.nan
    
df2['Flag'] = df2.apply(flag_df, axis = 1)

    student score   height  trigger1    trigger2    trigger3    Flag
0   A       100     7       84          99          114         Yellow
1   B       96      4       95          110         125         Red
2   C       80      9       15          30          45          NaN
3   D       105     5       78          93          108         Yellow
4   E       156     3       16          31          46          Orange
```

Note: You can do this with a very nested np.where but I prefer to apply a function for multiple if-else

Edit: answering @Cecilia's questions

1. what is the returned object is not strings but some calculations, for example, for the first condition, we want to return df['height']*2

Not sure what you tried but you can return a derived value instead of string using

```
def flag_df(df):

    if (df['trigger1'] <= df['score'] < df['trigger2']) and (df['height'] < 8):
        return df['height']*2
    elif (df['trigger2'] <= df['score'] < df['trigger3']) and (df['height'] < 8):
        return df['height']*3
    elif (df['trigger3'] <= df['score']) and (df['height'] < 8):
        return df['height']*4
    elif (df['height'] > 8):
        return np.nan
```

2. what if there are 'NaN' values in osome columns and I want to use df['xxx'] is None as a condition, the code seems like not working

Again not sure what code did you try but using pandas `isnull` would do the trick

```
def flag_df(df):

    if pd.isnull(df['height']):
        return df['height']
    elif (df['trigger1'] <= df['score'] < df['trigger2']) and (df['height'] < 8):
        return df['height']*2
    elif (df['trigger2'] <= df['score'] < df['trigger3']) and (df['height'] < 8):
        return df['height']*3
    elif (df['trigger3'] <= df['score']) and (df['height'] < 8):
        return df['height']*4
    elif (df['height'] > 8):
        return np.nan
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.. can you please help me to derive 2 more columns based on this condition. my original question was to derive 3 columns but edited because of confusing. can you able to see first post before editing?

Comment: Change your return statement to this: return  '{} score {} greater than {} and less than height 5'.format(df['student'], df['score'],  df['trigger1']). I have done it for first condition, use similar format for the rest of the conditions

Comment: Hi what is the returned object is not strings but some calculations, for example, for the first condition, we want to return `df['height']*2`?

Comment: and what if there'are 'NaN' values in osome columns and I want to use `df['xxx'] is None` as a condition, the code seems like not working

Comment: @Cecilia, please see the edits

Comment: What if I need to modify two columns (not just one as in the example: `Flag`).  How can I return the values from the function? I tried something like `return "yellow", "oil"` and received them as  `df2['Flag'], df2['Flag2'] = ...` or `df2[['Flag', 'Flag2']] = ....`. Can you help me @Vaishali? or someone?

Comment: I found it. returnning a list with the values as `return ["yellow", "oil"]`, and then using  option `expand` in `result_types` as in `df2[['Flag', 'Flag2']]  = df2.apply(flag_df, axis = 1, result_type='expand')`

Answer (score 18):

Here is a way to use `numpy.select()` for doing this with neat code, scalable and faster:

```
conditions = [
    (df2['trigger1'] <= df2['score']) & (df2['score'] < df2['trigger2']) & (df2['height'] < 8),
    (df2['trigger2'] <= df2['score']) & (df2['score'] < df2['trigger3']) & (df2['height'] < 8),
    (df2['trigger3'] <= df2['score']) & (df2['height'] < 8),
    (df2['height'] > 8)
]

choices = ['Red','Yellow','Orange', np.nan]
df['Flag1'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=np.nan)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use also apply with a custom function on axis 1 like this :

```
def color_selector(x):
    if (x['trigger1'] <= x['score'] < x['trigger2']) and (x['height'] < 8):
        return 'Red'
    elif (x['trigger2'] <= x['score'] < x['trigger3']) and (x['height'] < 8):
        return 'Yellow'
    elif (x['trigger3'] <= x['score']) and (x['height'] < 8):
        return 'Orange'
    elif (x['height'] > 8):
        return ''
df2 = df2.assign(flag=df2.apply(color_selector, axis=1))
```

you will get something like this :
[image]