# Multiple if conditions in pandas dataframe - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, nan

I'm following the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48569166/multiple-if-else-conditions-in-pandas-dataframe-and-derive-multiple-columns)

I have a `df` like this:

```
score_1   score_2  
1.11        NaN      
2.22        3.33      
NaN         3.33      
NaN         NaN
........
```

The rule for calculating `final_score` is that we require at least one of the scores to be `non-null`, if one of the scores in NULL, then final_score will equal to another score (it has all the weights)
This is the code to replicate:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
            'score_1': [1.11, 2.22, np.nan],
            'score_2': [np.nan, 3.33, 3.33]
        })

def final_score(df):
    if (df['score_1'] != np.nan) and (df['score_2'] != np.nan):
        print('I am condition one')
        return df['score_1'] * 0.2 + df['score_2'] * 0.8

    elif (df['score_1'] == np.nan) and (df['score_2'] != np.nan):
        print('I am the condition two')
        return df['score_2']

    elif (df['score_1'] != np.nan) and (df['score_2'] == np.nan):
        print('I am the condition three')
        return df['score_1']

    elif (df['score_1'] == np.nan) and (df['score_2'] == np.nan):
        print('I am the condition four')
        return np.nan

df['final_score'] = df.apply(final_score, axis=1)
print(df)
```

This gave me output:

```
score_1   score_2  final_score
1.11        NaN       NaN
2.22        3.33      3.108
NaN         3.33      NaN
NaN         NaN       NaN
........
```

But my expected output is below:

```
score_1   score_2  final_score
1.11        NaN       1.11
2.22        3.33      3.108
NaN         3.33      3.33
NaN         NaN       NaN
........
```

The first and third row are not the result I'm expecting, can someone help me, what's wrong with my code? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets appy your conditions using np.where

```
df['final_score'] =np.where(df.notna().all(1),df['score_1'] * 0.2 + df['score_2'] * 0.8,df.mean(1))



   score_1  score_2  final_score
0     1.11      NaN        1.110
1     2.22     3.33        3.108
2      NaN     3.33        3.330
3      NaN      NaN          NaN
```

Comment: Hi thanks, this is much more simplified, but not very readable for people not familiar with what I'm doing, just wondering why we use `df.mean(1)` here?

Comment: df.mean(1) along the axis 1 that is mean along the rows. np.where(condition, apply if condition is, apply this if not condition is met)

Comment: Hi if I still want to use my original code, how can I update it to make it work? Because your one-line code seems not working for my 'large' dataset when there're lots of other columns, so I still want to figure out what's the issue in my original code, thanks.

Comment: np.where is vectorized and much faster, unless speed and compute resources are a non issue

Comment: but problem is I have other columns with different values, and this one-line code doesn't work for me, I can't just use `df.mean(1)`

Comment: df['final_score'] =np.where(df[['score_1','score_2']].notna().all(1),df['score_1'] * 0.2 + df['score_2'] * 0.8,df.mean(1)). Try that and let me know. Typing on  phone so didn't test. Basically subsetting the two columns to check if all of them are NaN

Comment: `df['final_score'] =np.where(df[['score_1','score_2']].notna().all(1),df['score_1'] * 0.2 + df['score_2'] * 0.8,df[['score_1','score_2']].mean(1))` this works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

using np.isnan() for comparison should solve the problem

Comment: Hi can you be more specific? I tried `elif df['score_1'].isnan() and df['score_2'].notnan():` but not working

Comment: what i meant was to use np.isnan() in the following way: `elif (np.isnan(df['score_1']) and not np.isnan(df['score_2'])):`