# Filtering a dataframe with several or statements

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with about several columns that have conditions that I wish to filter in various combinations.  I want to keep all columns where any set of conditions is met.

For instance if four  th conditions are

1. city = "NY" and weather ="Rainy"
2. city 'Philly' and weather    ="Sunny" and time = "Day"
3. city 'Philly' and weather ="Rainy" and time = "Night"
4. city 'Albany' and  time = "Night"

I want to keep all rows where any of those four conditions are met it would be expressed as

writing that out with a data.iloc["city"] with a bunch of ands or or sounds messy and there is room for error as my conditions grow

What do you think is the best way to handle this?

For clarification the below dataframe is before running the procedure

| City | Weather | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NYC | Sunny | Day |
| NYC | Rainy | Night |
| Philly | Sunny | Day |
| Philly | Rainy | Day |
| Philly | Rainy | Night |
| Seattle | Windy | Day |
| Albany | Rainy | Night |
| Albany | Sunny | Day |

The following is the resulting dataframe

| City | Weather | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NYC | Rainy | Night |
| Philly | Sunny | Day |
| Philly | Rainy | Night |
| Albany | Rainy | Night |

Answer (score 0):

you could use '&' and '|' like this:

```
df[
((df['City']=='NYC') & (df['Weather']=='Rainy'))
| ((df['City']=='Philly') & (df['Weather']=='Sunny') & (df['Time']=='Day'))
| ((df['City']=='Philly') & (df['Weather']=='Rainy') & (df['Time']=='Night'))
| ((df['City']=='Albany') & (df['Time']=='Night'))
  ]
```

Comment: In practice I have about 7 more conditions than this, and I did not want to do this. Is there a better way?

Comment: hmm, not sure, I think it depends on your specific logic, if it could be expressed differently

Comment: yeah I want to avoid the and / or (&/|)

Comment: maybe try this approach:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48569166/multiple-if-else-conditions-in-pandas-dataframe-and-derive-multiple-columns